# CreateInstance says it's a method by is used like a type

Tags: c#, abstract-class, createinstance

I have a base program that impliments an abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public AbstractClass (MyObject object1, MyOtherObject object2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the abstract class");
    }

    public abstract bool Function1();
    <other abstract functions>
}
```

Right now I build and compile seperate versions of my application when I want to do different things and have implemented different abstract classes for these things. I find this to be tedious.

I'd like to be able to take this line of code

```
new MySuperSpecialClassOfThings(param1, (MyObject obj1, MyOtherObject obj2) => 
{
    return new NotAnAbstractClass(obj1, obj2);
}, true);
```

And change it to something like:

```
new MySuperSpecialClassOfThings(param1, (MyObject obj1, MyOtherObject obj2) => 
{
    return new System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(config.NonAbstractClassName), new object[] { obj1, obj2 });
}, true);
```

Where `config.NonAbstractClassName` is a string provided in a configuration file. This fails, though, with the error:
`'System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext, string[])' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'`

`obj1` and `obj2` are not strings. They are classes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `new` before `CreateInstance`:

```
new MySuperSpecialClassOfThings(param1, (MyObject obj1, MyOtherObject obj2) => 
{
    return (AbstractClass)System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(config.NonAbstractClassName), new object[] { obj1, obj2 });
}, true);
```

Comment: That results in `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'MyNameSpace.AbstractClass'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @Andy You should cast to `AbstractClass` since `CreateInstance` returns `object`. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "new" keyword..CreateInstance return new instance of object based on type on parameter..so basically you don't need "new" keyword